# How to add filter to hide out of stock products when searching for Upsells and Cross-sells in admin panel on the Linked Products tab (in woocommerce)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On a single product, inside the admin panel, on the Linked Products tab (on woocommerce), i can set up Up-Sells and Cross-Sells Products. I can add the product i wish to link to by searching for it.

At the moment search gives all products, even the ones that are out of stock. I would like if i write down an id of a product that is out of stock, it won't appear on the list.

The function that is responsible for json result is

```
public static function json_search_products_and_variations() {
self::json_search_products( '', true );
}

public static function json_search_products( $term = '', $include_variations = false ) {
check_ajax_referer( 'search-products', 'security' );

if ( empty( $term ) && isset( $_GET['term'] ) ) {
    $term = (string) wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['term'] ) );
}

if ( empty( $term ) ) {
    wp_die();
}

if ( ! empty( $_GET['limit'] ) ) {
    $limit = absint( $_GET['limit'] );
} else {
    $limit = absint( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_json_search_limit', 30 ) );
}

$include_ids = ! empty( $_GET['include'] ) ? array_map( 'absint', (array) wp_unslash( $_GET['include'] ) ) : array();
$exclude_ids = ! empty( $_GET['exclude'] ) ? array_map( 'absint', (array) wp_unslash( $_GET['exclude'] ) ) : array();

$exclude_types = array();
if ( ! empty( $_GET['exclude_type'] ) ) {
    // Support both comma-delimited and array format inputs.
    $exclude_types = wp_unslash( $_GET['exclude_type'] ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.ValidatedSanitizedInput.InputNotSanitized
    if ( ! is_array( $exclude_types ) ) {
        $exclude_types = explode( ',', $exclude_types );
    }

    // Sanitize the excluded types against valid product types.
    foreach ( $exclude_types as &$exclude_type ) {
        $exclude_type = strtolower( trim( $exclude_type ) );
    }
    $exclude_types = array_intersect(
        array_merge( array( 'variation' ), array_keys( wc_get_product_types() ) ),
        $exclude_types
    );
}

$data_store = WC_Data_Store::load( 'product' );
$ids        = $data_store->search_products( $term, '', (bool) $include_variations, false, $limit, $include_ids, $exclude_ids );


$products = array();


foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
    $product_object = wc_get_product( $id );

    if ( ! wc_products_array_filter_readable( $product_object ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    $formatted_name = $product_object->get_formatted_name();
    $managing_stock = $product_object->managing_stock();

    if ( in_array( $product_object->get_type(), $exclude_types, true ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    if ( $managing_stock && ! empty( $_GET['display_stock'] ) ) { 
        $stock_amount = $product_object->get_stock_quantity();
        /* Translators: %d stock amount */
        $formatted_name .= ' &ndash; ' . sprintf( __( 'Stock: %d', 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $stock_amount, $product_object ) );
    }

    $products[ $product_object->get_id() ] = rawurldecode( $formatted_name );
        

}

wp_send_json( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_json_search_found_products', $products ) );

}
```

Before wp_send_json(...) how can i exclude from $products array the outofstock products?

Answer (score 1):

Before

```
$products[ $product_object->get_id() ] = rawurldecode( $formatted_name );
```

the code

```
if ('outofstock' === $product_object->get_stock_status()){
            continue;
}
```

worked for me.